# Calling save() on a model will update every row in the database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got the following function in a migration file. The migration is to add a new column, and then update the columns of the existing entries:

```php
<?php

private function updatePlans()
{
    $plans = PlanProvider::query()->get();

    foreach ($plans as $plan) {
        $plan->num_adults = 1;

        if (stripos($plan->rate_name, 'couple') !== false) {
            $plan->num_adults = 2;
        }
        $plan->save();
    }
}
```

Now, what's happening here is that when I call `save()`, it's updating EVERY model, instead of the one inside the loop. I have a similar function for another migration, and it works as expected. Why would this update every model rather than just the one?

Comment: There isn't a where clause when you fetch the plans: `$plans = PlanProvider::query()->get();` will get all plans from your table.

Comment: try `where`. Not sre wh that is happening

Comment: @adam: I don't need a where. I am getting all the rows. But I'm looping through each one, modifying, then saving. Again, I do nearly the exact same thing on another migration.

Comment: I think `::query()` will give you a builder. Try using `PlanProvider::get()`.

Answer (score 0):

`$plans` is a Collection that contains all your "plans".
Your `$plan->save();` is outside your `if` conditions, so obviously it updates every single row, no matter if it has 1 or 2 `num_adults`

Comment: The `$plan->save()` is inside the `foreach`. Being outside the `if` makes no difference, as it is in the scope of the `foreach`. Again, I can't emphasize this enough, I have the same exact function on another migration that works as I'd expected.

Comment: Do you mean all entries/rows in your table have ```num_adults``` = ```1``` (or ```2```), while you expect some to have ```1``` and some others to have ```2``` ? You're not clear enough. Consider adding your migration as well.

Comment: I expect a mix of `1` and `2` to occur. Not sure how that isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {


        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:subscribers'
        ]);

        $subscriber = new Subscriber();
        $subscriber->email = $request->email;
        $subscriber->save();
        Toastr::success('You are Successfully Added Our Subscriber List:)','Success');
        return redirect()->back();

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

## you can try this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PlanProvider extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'plan_provider';
    
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;
}


private function updatePlans()
{
    $plans = PlanProvider::findOrFail(id);
    $plans->num_adults = 1;
    $plans->save();
    
    return redirect()->back();  
}
```